# How to cut paragraph white spaces of a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, whitespace, trim, removing-whitespace

I'm currently writing my own Content-Management-System using OOP PHP and the Model-View-Controller file architecture. Due to said MVC system, I need to dynamically render the content of a given post into a defined element. I already wrote a script for the purpose and it's working fine. Problems come into count when there is a blog text with paragraph white spaces (inside a string). This apparently causes issues, because it is actively destroying the string form of e.g. '' which directly leads to the string not getting executed in the browser approprately. What I'm saying is, that if there are so much white spaces (due to a paragraph of text) inside a string, the markup gets apparently destroyed and as a result it is not rendered at all or as it should be.

Additionally to this consideration/conjecture I'm getting an error message of "Uncaught: Syntaxerror: Invalid or unexptected token" which is without any doubt in direct combination to my description above. When I'm clicking onto the filename at the end of the error report in console, I'm getting redirected to an completely empty page, so that will not be valid way for debugging.

Since this is a general question of JavaScript and/or PHP opportunities when it comes to string manipulation, I am not in need of providing any code snippets. However, you can check out my Github for further code inspecitons anyways.

Here is the link to the project: https://github.com/F9lke/basic-cms. Please be aware that comments and messages are written in German in the current State of the project. This will definetly change in the future. The script I'm talking about is to be found in the renderOutput.class.php in the model/render directory.

Do you know a solution for this problem or have you already experienced a similar situation? Please let me know and have a nice day!

Thanks in advance, J0nny

** EDIT **

I think I explained the problem quite well, but I will try to get more specific. I meant in my extensive description above, that the paragraph white spaces of text apparently break the quotes. If you looked into my script I provided by giving you the projects GitHub, you would notice that I am giving the text through a php variable to a JavaScript variable. This is neccessary, but can cause significant issues due to the quotes. At this state I wrote it in the following way:

```
echo "targetClass.innerHTML = '$text' + targetClass.innerHTML;\n";
```

Problems can occur if done in a different way, because the quotes wouldn't match up of the contained markup. In order to understand this, you have to take into consideration, that there is actual markup rendered by this method as shown in the following example:

```
echo "targetClass.innerHTML = '<div class="exampleClass">foo</div>' + targetClass.innerHTML;\n";
```

Now again the problem I described already above; If there is a post with a text containing several white-spaces (=paragraphs for example) created, then the markup apparently stops getting executed and the browser is logging an error of "Invalid or unexptected Token".

That's why I came up with the question on how to cut these white spaces. Hopefully, you can understand this issues better now.

J0nny

Comment: Not clear why whitespace in html would break in browser. Provide a [mcve] and scale down the written text to a bare minimum to outline only the specific problem

Comment: Please edit your question, to include the problem, the code related to the problem, expected result and the given results with any errors.

Comment: Please learn about PHP-FIG standards. To be honest your code is very bad.

Comment: in jquery you can just do `$.trim(string)`  without it you can do something like `string.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '');`  If you want to minify the HTML I wrote a lexer for another answer a wile ago, you can get it here on my [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/MISC/blob/master/Lexers/HtmlMinifier.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For quoted strings you can use the little known HEREDOC and NEWDOC,

> This is neccessary, but can cause significant issues due to the quotes.

A few notes

- HEREDOC acts like `"` as far as variable interpolation is concerned
- NEWDOC acts like `'`
- For both the ending tag has to be on a **line by itself**, with no space before or after or it wont work.

OK so some examples

```
  //heredoc
echo <<<HTML
targetClass.innerHTML = '<div class="exampleClass">foo</div>' + targetClass.innerHTML;

HTML;

 //newdoc
echo <<<'HTML'
targetClass.innerHTML = '<div class="exampleClass">foo</div>' + targetClass.innerHTML;

HTML;
```

The tag `HTML` can be anything you wan't.  So whats the difference as I said about variable interpolation, but I will show you.

```
$foo = "hello world";
//heredoc
echo <<<TAG
    $foo
TAG;
//newdoc
echo <<<'TAG'
    $foo
TAG;
```

Output

```
 //heredoc
  hello world
 //newdoc
  $foo
```

Oh, and if the benefit is not obvious, well you no longer have to use quotes in PHP for the string, so you are free to use both the `'` and `"` with no escaping for PHP.

The other choice is to escape them like a normal person, but that is boring...

```
echo "targetClass.innerHTML = '<div class=\"exampleClass\">foo</div>' + targetClass.innerHTML;\n";
```

See without the `\` PHP thinks this is the string:

```
 echo "targetClass.innerHTML = '<div class="
```

Then the rest causes a syntax error, well unless I missed the actual question within that wall to text you wrote.

One word of "caution"

> If there is a post ... which directly leads to the string not getting executed in the browser appropriately.

If site users can save anything to this, such as make a post, then you are opening your site up to XSS (Cross site scripting)  Where a malicious user will insert Javascript into a post, and then when viewed by other users that javascript will steal things like session cookies and send them to the previously mentioned malicious user.  Then that user can potentially Hijack any login sessions the unfortunate user had who viewed that post had (which might be things other then your site).  So yea be careful executing HTML supplied by 3rd parties.

Enyjoy.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your answer! How can I prevent these XSS attacks then? Maybe, by searching the string for script tags?

Comment: I think there is a library, HTML purifier I've never used it but I think it should work.  Typically what I do is a version of BBcode builtin board like this https://www.phpbb.com/community/help/bbcode